How to Control TP-Link Tapo Plugs from Another Network Using PlugP100 or Python-Kasa Libraries
I am using the PlugP100 / Python-Kasa library to control my TP-Link smart plugs. Currently, I can send commands to the plugs when I am on the same network and know their IP addresses. However, I have plugs located on different networks, and I cannot directly access those networks, so the commands won't work in such cases.
When I am not on the same network, device discovery still works, but I cannot retrieve the IP addresses of those devices.
How can I control or interact with my plugs from a different network? Are there alternative solutions for remote control using this library or other methods?
is there a MQTT way to do it?
python-kasa:
async def main():
    dev = await Discover.discover_single("192.168.x.x",username=EMAIL,password=PASSWORD)
    await dev.turn_on()
    await dev.update()

plugp100:
connectedDevices = [] # List to store connected devices
async def example_discovery(credentials: AuthCredential):
    discovered = await TapoDiscovery.scan(timeout=5)
    device_objects = []  # List to store created Device objects
    for discovered_device in discovered:
        try:
            # Initialize the Tapo device
            device = await discovered_device.get_tapo_device(credentials)
            # Update the device state
            await device.update()
            # Extract raw_state and create a Device object
            raw_state = device.raw_state
            device_objects.append(raw_state)
            # print(new_device)
            await device.client.close()
        
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f"Failed to update {discovered_device.ip} {discovered_device.device_type}", exc_info=e)
    return device_objects  # Return the list of created Device objects

async def connectAll(rawDeviceList):
    for device in rawDeviceList:
        device_configuration = DeviceConnectConfiguration(
            host=device.ip,
            credentials=AuthCredential(EMAIL, PASSWORD)
        )
        connectedDevice = await connect(device_configuration)
        await connectedDevice.update()
        connectedDevices.append(connectedDevice)
    return connectedDevices

async def toggle_device_state(ip, state, connected_devices):
    for device in connected_devices:
        if ip == device.raw_state.get('ip', 'Unknown'):
            if state == "on":
                await device.turn_on()
            elif state == "off":
                await device.turn_off()
            else:
                print("Invalid state. Please enter 'on' or 'off'.")
    

